# Javascript issue with code developing a credit card schedule

Tags: javascript, object-literal

I am working on a amortization schedule for a credit card loan. I keep getting one error or another when running the code I've written. It's "Unexpected identifier", to which I can't seem to locate where that is.

Please help me to straighten the code better so it will run the schedule

```
function displayWelcome() {
 var balance = 1500;
 var interest = 0.18;
 var minimumpaymentRate = 0.02;
 console.log("Welcome! \nThis program will determine the time to pay off 
 a 
 credit card and the interest paid based on the current balance, the 
 interest rate, and the monthly payments made.")
 console.log("Balance on your credit card: $" + balance.toFixed(2))
 console.log("Interest Rate: " + (interest * 100) + "%")
 console.log("Assuming a minimum payment of 2% of the balance ($20 min)")
 console.log("Your minimum payment would be: $" + minimumPaymentment)
 console.log("\nYear    Balance     Payment #     Interest Paid      
 Minimum Payment")
 }

function calculateminimumPaymentment(balance, minimumPaymentRate) {
 return Math.max(20, balance * minimumPaymentRate);
}

function generatePaymentId() {
 var count = 0;
 function paymentId() {
  count ++;           
  return count;
 }
return paymentId;
};

function processPaymentSchedule(balance, interest, minimumPayment) {
 var id = generatePaymentId();
 var year = 1;
 var payments = 1;
 var interestPaid = 0;
 var yearChange;

 while (balance > 0) {
 yearChange = false;

 if (payments % 12 == 0) {
  year++
  yearChange = true;
 }
 interestPaid += balance * interest / 12;
 balance = Math.max(0, balance - (minimumPayment - balance * interest / 
 12));
 minimumPayment = Math.max(20, balance * minimumPaymentRate);
 payments++;
 }
}

function displayPayment(pmt){
 var pmt = {
 balance: 1500,
 minimumPaymentRate: 0.02,
 interest: 0.18
 console.log((yearChange ? year:" ") + "        " + pmt.balance + "      
 " 
 + payments + "              " + pmt.interest + "             " + 
 pmt.minimumPaymentRate);
    return displayPayment
    };
}

displayWelcome()

processPaymentSchedule(balance, interest, minimumPayment);
```

The expected results should be:

An amortization schedule that shows: Year, Balance, Interest

UPDATE:

I have updated with the suggestions listed below, but now am getting this error:

[minimumPayment is not defined error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fpED4.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating multiline strings in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/805107/creating-multiline-strings-in-javascript). You get the error because JS `"` and `'` string literals aren't multi-line by default.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is really buggy. There are several errors:

- the multiline string should be created with `` instead of quotes
- function displayPayment: move console.log and return outside of an object
- declare balance, interest, minimumPayment outside of function so that you can use these variables